# Docker compose cache dependensies but not the code

Tags: spring-boot, docker, caching, docker-compose, web-applications

I am a Java backend developer and i want to dockerize the backend part in order for my front end college to easily run in on his local machine. I will describe my problem based on demo project. So the demo project consists out of mysql and a spring boot web app. The app is works fine when i am using **docker-compose**, all the dependecies are download before the start and the endpoint "test" is returning "Some message". The problem occurse when i change the code and **docker-compose down** and **docker-compose up** the app, the code isnt changing. What i can do to solve this problem is to package the app on local machine and then deliver it to docker, but then the local machine has to has maven in order to compile it, and i dont want that, i want my college just to use docker and dont care about how all this thing works. Another solution could be not to cache, but then the dependencies have to be downloaded every time we restart the app, that is also not acceptable. So my question is "**Is there a way to cache the dependecies (to download it once) but not the code, so that when i am starting the app, a fresh app ,with updated code, would compile?**" (Sorry for my english). Here is the demo project that i am testing on:

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("message")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Message getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return messageRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Message save(@RequestBody Message message){
        return messageRepository.save(message);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String ss(){
        return "Some message";
    }

}
```

The model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message,Long> {}
```

property file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: root
    password: 123456789
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    sql-script-encoding: UTF-8
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Docker file that is in root of the spring project:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-11
WORKDIR /demo
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install package -Dmaven.test.skip
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456789
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./demo
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "root",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "123456789",
        "spring.jpa.database-platform" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .:/root
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:
```

Comment: There is the shorthand notation `-DskipTests` for the maven argument `-Dmaven.test.skip`

Comment: I made an error in naming the image. Try my edit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In order to not download the dependencies, i need to cache them in upper layer and code in lower layer so that when i change the code, i dont have to redownload the dependencies. The docker file looks like this.

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-11-slim
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY src/ src/
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And as @valerij-dobler said i need to remove my container in order for my code changes to take effect

```
docker-compose down && docker image rm -f myapp && docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

The image for your app is built and it reuses the same image for every next `docker-compose up`.

If you want to force the rebuild you could use `docker-compose up --build`. Alternatively, you could remove the image by hand. But first, you should name your image, by using this property:

```yaml
services:
  #...
  app:
    #...
    build: ./demo
    image: my_app
```

then by using `docker image rm my_app` you could remove it. After that, the `docker-compose up` should rebuild your app.
So you could give your frontend colleague following one-liner:

```
docker image rm my_app && docker-compose up -d
```

Note that `-d` runs the docker-compose detached from the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunatly nor using "docker-compose up --build" neither adding app name and using comand "docker image rm my_app && docker-compose up -d" worked for me. This solutions updates the code but forces to redownload the dependencies

Comment: Did you also `docker-compose down` the network before?

Comment: Yes, i also tried this "docker-compose down && docker image rm myapp && docker-compose up" but it still redownload the dependencies. Maybe the problem is with the volumes?

Comment: Did it really download the dependencies? Usually, docker checks if you already have the required layers downloaded and uses cached versions.

Comment: Yes i did, they are on by root folder with the docker-compose.yml file. They have been downloaded there when i am starting docker-compose

Comment: Note that a message like `=> CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/mariadb:10.5.6@sha256:5c754274a61b614d847090f80152b39bc68a3fa65af66e52db0505d3c2299436` would appear if you used locally available layers.

Answer (score 0):

1.In your project create a jar. since i use eclipse i just click maven install or maven build to create jar.

2. In your docker file you must specified the jar file.
3. In your docker compose specify also the jar, where is the jar, jar file name, the port and etc . And this will create container for you application.

4.Inorder to run with updated code you must use this comman for docker `docker-compose -f dockercomposeYourFile.yaml up --build`.

5. If there is other container in you docker compose just use `depends_on` then if the conatiner need to wait and cause to stop you need `restart: always` or anything about `restart`

Comment: I know that this will work. I mentioned this solution in the question, the problem is that, my frontend college doesnt have to know how to install maven in order to make jar file. I want to make the process of installing updated version of backend as easy as possible, thats why i am using maven:3.8.4-jdk-11 image, to compile the code in the container and not on local machine. Anyway, thank you for spairing time to help me ))

Comment: It is totally fine to have the Dockerfile built the jar.